# How should I create a library targetting .NET Framework 4.5.1 and .NET Standard 1.3 in VS 2017 RC?

Tags: .net, portable-class-library, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

This is my first time trying anything that targets more than just a .NET Framework. I can't seem to do it from the GUI. I've tried project type 'Class Library (Portable)' and project type 'Class Library (.NET Standard)'. I can change a 'Class Library (Portable)' to target .NET Standard but then I can't select anything else. I'm not sure if I should try to change the .csproj of 'Class Library (.NET Standard)' or the project.json of 'Class Library (Portable)', I just want whatever is most future-proof.

Comment: Open csproj and add another target framework tag. Go to .NET Blog at MSDN Blogs and read its recent news.

Comment: That didn't seem to work, despite what https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt791801 says. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but only one of the targets gets recognized. But I tried a different syntax and it seems to be working: <TargetFrameworks>net451;netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks>. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Because the SDK has been moving fast. If you install the latest (like RC4), you should be able to get things work, https://github.com/dotnet/cli (scroll down to the download section on that page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of a few days ago the .csproj has been simplified and ease of use has improved. With the latest version of VS 2017 RC, I create such a library by creating a new 'Class Library (.NET Standard)', which has this default .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And I edit it by hand (I don't see a way to do it through the UI) to be this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;net452</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The 'Target framework' drop down under the project's Properties pane then becomes grayed out. By building you can verify separate netstandard1.3 and net452 folders under bin\Debug. Be aware of the following issue if you're creating a NuGet package on build, which may mislead you into thinking you've done something incorrectly: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4289.

Comment: The subtly of the 's' in the `TargetFramework` => `TargetFrameworks` part of the answer got me.
It wasn't until I tried to build and got the '... to multi-target use the 'targetframeworks' property instead' error that I saw it. :)